# NiFi PutHiveStreaming processor with Hive: Failed connecting to EndPoint

Tags: java, hive, apache-nifi, orc, hortonworks-dataflow

Someone would help on this issue with Nifi 1.3.0 and Hive. I get the same error with hive 1.2 and Hive 2.1.1. The hive table is **partioned** , **bucketed** and stored as **ORC** format.

**The partition is created on hdfs but data failed on writing stage**. Please check the logs as below:

```
[5:07 AM] papesdiop: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='mydb', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
[5:13 AM] papesdiop: I get in log see next, hope it might help too:
[5:13 AM] papesdiop: Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.TransactionError: Unable to acquire lock on {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='mydb', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
  at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:578)
```

**FULL TRACE LOGS:**

reconnect.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.lock(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor380.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:152)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.lock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:573)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransaction(HiveEndPoint.java:547)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:261)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.(HiveWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveUtils.makeHiveWriter(HiveUtils.java:46)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.makeHiveWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:964)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.getOrCreateWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:875)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$null$40(PutHiveStreaming.java:676)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:127)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$44(PutHiveStreaming.java:673)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2136)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2106)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:627)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$36(PutHiveStreaming.java:551)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:551)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-09-07 06:41:31,015 DEBUG [Timer-4] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=13ed53d2-015e-1000-c7b1-5af434c38751] Start sending heartbeat on all writers
2017-09-07 06:41:31,890 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
2017-09-07 06:41:31,893 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
2017-09-07 06:41:31,911 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=13ed53d2-015e-1000-c7b1-5af434c38751] Failed to create HiveWriter for endpoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.(HiveWriter.java:79)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveUtils.makeHiveWriter(HiveUtils.java:46)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.makeHiveWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:964)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.getOrCreateWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:875)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$null$40(PutHiveStreaming.java:676)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:127)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$44(PutHiveStreaming.java:673)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2136)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2106)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:627)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$36(PutHiveStreaming.java:551)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:551)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$TxnBatchFailure: Failed acquiring Transaction Batch from EndPoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:264)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.(HiveWriter.java:73)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.TransactionError: Unable to acquire lock on {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=[dev] }
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:578)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransaction(HiveEndPoint.java:547)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:261)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.lock(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor380.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:152)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.lock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:573)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
2017-09-07 06:41:31,911 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=13ed53d2-015e-1000-c7b1-5af434c38751] Error connecting to Hive endpoint: table guys at thrift://localhost:9083
2017-09-07 06:41:31,911 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=13ed53d2-015e-1000-c7b1-5af434c38751] has chosen to yield its resources; will not be scheduled to run again for 1000 milliseconds
2017-09-07 06:41:31,912 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=13ed53d2-015e-1000-c7b1-5af434c38751] Hive Streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to retry. org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://localhost:9083', database='default', table='guys', partitionVals=

***The Hive table***

> CREATE TABLE `mydb.guys`(
>     `firstname` string,
>     `lastname` string)
>   PARTITIONED BY (
>     `job` string)
>   CLUSTERED BY (
>     firstname)
>   INTO 10 BUCKETS
>   ROW FORMAT SERDE
>     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
>   STORED AS ORC
>   LOCATION
>     'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/papesdiop/guys'
>   TBLPROPERTIES ( 'transactional'='true')

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this is failing during the write to HDFS, perhaps your user does not have permissions to write to the target directory? If you have more information from the full stack trace please add it to your question, as it will help diagnose the problem. When I had this issue a while ago, it was because my NiFi user needed to be created on the target OS and added to the appropriate HDFS group(s) in order to get permission for PutHiveStreaming to write out to the ORC file(s) in HDFS.

Comment: Hi Matt, 
I use the same user for all services (hdfs, yarn, hiveserver2, metastore,nifi) . the partitions in hdfs are dynamically created but with empty files lie delta_0022710_0022714/bucket_00001_flush_length.

Full stacktrace log:

Comment: I edited issue with full trace logs. thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using Apache NiFi or Hortonworks DataFlow? Is your cluster Apache Hadoop or a distribution from a vendor? That error implies that there's a Thrift mismatch, which usually indicates incompatible versions

Comment: I'm using Apache Nifi-1.3.0  and hadoop-2.7.3
**.bashrc**

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/papesdiop/hadoop-2.7.3
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin
export NIFI_HOME=/home/papesdiop/nifi-1.3.0
export PATH=$PATH:$NIFI_HOME/bin
export ZEPPELIN_HOME=/home/papesdiop/zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all
export PATH=$PATH:$ZEPPELIN_HOME/bin
export HIVE_HOME=/home/papesdiop/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin`

Comment: Also this following hive query works well: 
`insert into table guys partition(job) values ( 'pape', 'diop','dev');`
seems the issue is related to nifi hivestreaming processor.

Hope it may help too. thanks